# Django queryset gets empty after if, but it shouldn't

Tags: html, django

Maybe the title is a bit confusing, English is not my primary language. I apologize about that. 
To the point: I have a table of clients that can be active or not, simple field that says 'yes' or 'no'. So in the html form I have a  Select input with 3 options: Indifferent (all clients, has value 0), yes (active clients, value 'yes'), no (not active, value 'no').

The thing is, when I want to get all the clients (active and inactive) the queryset becomes empty for a reason that I don't understand.

This is part of the html form:

```
<select name="ClienteActivo">
<option value="0" selected="selected">Indiferente</option>
<option value="Si">Si</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
</select>
```

This is the view:

```
def resultadosClienteAvanzadoView(request):

    #Here I retrieve all clients.
    clientes=ClientesCompradores.objects.all()

    #Active can be 0, yes or no. 0 means both, so no filter.
    active=request.GET.get('ClienteActivo')

    #If activo is not 0 then filter the clients.
    if active != 0:
        clientes=clientes.filter(nulo=active)

    #Create the context. Again, when active is 0 i want all the clients.
    context={
        'clientes':clientes,
        'cantidad':len(clientes)
    }
    return render(request,'catalog/resultadosClienteAvanzado.html',context)
```

If someone needs more info I have no problem providing it.

I'm sure it is a rookie mistake since I'm still learning Django.

Edit1:

nulo in the django models is like this:

```
nulo = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
```

It's a legacy DB that I'm working with it's a pain in the ass actually :/

Thanks in advance!

Edit2: There was a typo in

```
<option value="0" selected="selected">Indiferente</option>
```

The value is actually 0

Edit3: After all it was 'cause I was evaluating 0 as a int instead of a string. Thanks to Gytree for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RUNING:

```
active = request.GET.get("ClienteActivo")
```

- if the user select 'Indiferente' the active is `'0'` ( cero **string** )
- if the user
  select 'Si' the active is `'Si'`
- and if the user select 'No' the
  active is `'No'`

then when you ask

`active != 0:` alway be True beacouse antive olny can get values ( '0', 'No', 'Si')

then when python create the `queryset` use the `nulo = '0'` and you don't have a register with `nulo == '0'`

then the filter most be:

```
if active != '0'
```

or

```
if active in ('No', 'Si'):
```

Comment: There was a typo in the <option> field, in my code it's correctly 0. But I'm gonna try the other option you are providing!

Comment: Yep the if active in ('No', 'Si'): option works and does not empty the queryset. Thank you!

Comment: no vi la segunda edición. pero igual creo que al sacar el parámetro de la request. el '0' sigue siendo un string si mas no me equivoco.

Comment: Dios, es cierto! Probablemente es porque estaba evaluando el 0 como string en vez de como integer. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `nulo` is a Django BooleanField, use the following:

```
if active == 'Si':
    clientes = clientes.filter(nulo=True)
elif active == 'No':
    clientes = clientes.filter(nulo=False)
```

Comment: Nope, nulo is a a charfield.

Comment: I've added it to the Original post!

Comment: In that case the other answer is correct. But I strongly suggest (from years of experience, with many other languages as well as Django/Python) that you change `nulo` to a BooleanField if possible. It will make queries faster and remove (human) language dependence from the model and in general be a little more straightforward.